# How to make 2 selections inside container?

Tags: jquery, selector

I'd like to make 2 selections inside container (Container). The code looks as follows:

```
    <div id="Container">
        <div id="Div6" class="one">A</div>
        <div id="Div7" class="two">B</div>
        <div id="Div8" class="one">C</div>
        <div id="Div9" class="two">D</div>
        <div id="Div10" class="one">E</div>
    </div>
```

First, I want to select all elements with class "one" and than inside that wrapped set of 3 elements (Div6, Div8 and Div10) to select only Div10?

Comment: `$('.one#Div10')` ??? [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/MMsTA/) or perhaps i'm missing something !!! or even `$('#Div10')` as `ids` should be unique !!

Comment: why not selecting `$("#Div10")` directly?

Comment: @ManseUK. maybe it's just an example?

Comment: @gdoron i would imagine it is .... and I probably dont understand the question  ... but to select a single element (quote *to select only Div10*) using an id should just be `$('#<id>')` surely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer would be to select them independently, like so:

```
$('.one') //a collection of elements whith class .one
$('#Div10') //the element with ID Div10
```

If for some reason you have to select the classes first, then filter out just the element with the right ID, do:

```
var elm = $('.one').filter('#Div10');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know I can select it directly, but wanted this way for the sake of learning. This is what I needed: $("#Container").find(".one").filter("#Div10").text("OK");

Comment: @tesicg if you are accessing a single DOM element using its `id` attribute the simplest way is `('#<id>')` ... using the filter and selecting other classes is a waste of processing power ...

Comment: @tesicg - yes, that will work, you can also do `$(".one", "#Container").filter("#Div10").text("OK");`, but that's just a shortcut for `find()`, and doing it the way you do is probably better. As ManseUK says, it's fine for learning, but ID's are unique and there's no need to filter something unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Container .one').doFoo().filter('#Div10').fooElse();
```

**Example:**

```
$('#Container .one').fadeOut()
                    .filter('#Div10').fadeIn();​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AxAJn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be two steps? First you can call `$('#Div10')` to directly get the div. Or use `$('.one#Div10')` to only get a div with both class `one` AND id `Div10`.

Answer (score 0):

this selector get 3 divs with class `one`

```
$('#Container > .one');
```

to reduce the selection, starting from the previous one

```
$('#Container > .one').filter($('#Div10'));
```

See [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) documentation

Comment: Why you filter by a jQuery object? it doesn't make any sense. You select the element, to get it only... just use it. `:)`

Comment: I know :( but it is what OP asked :  _...and then inside that wrapped set of 3 elements ... select only Div10_ and looking at jquery documentation it's a valid example.